# Are there any plans for the mobile version of the website to incorporate the new top bar design?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, top-bar

Given that the top nav is changing for desktop, are there any plans to bring similar changes (notably same button positioning) on to mobile?

Comment: we may adjust some positioning and maybe layout but we don't have any big plans for mobile at the moment. we're focused on desktop right now.

Comment: @Paweł:  That should likely be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3):

According to [@Paweł's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343239/are-there-any-plans-for-the-mobile-version-of-the-website-to-incorporate-the-new#comment444453_343239), there are no short-term plans for updating the design of the mobile version of the site.  His comment was:

> we may adjust some positioning and maybe layout but we don't have any big plans for mobile at the moment. we're focused on desktop right now. – Paweł♦ Feb 8 at 9:31

So, it looks as though it will be some time before any significant changes beyond "positioning and maybe layout" occur on the mobile website.