# Top navigation painful on mobile device

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

There are certain SO features I use that are not available on the SE app, so I (prefer to) use Chrome (on iPhone) in "fullsite" mode.

The new nav bar doesn't zoom - it widens to the right (left edge locked) as you zoom, but widens so quickly that before it becomes legible, the right hand side (the bit I want to see) is off screen.

When zooming in portrait orientation, the nav detail is still microscopic as it disappears off screen to the right - the nav bar numeric detail (eg "achievements" etc) is never legible in portrait.

When zooming in landscape, it is barely legible before it disappears, but the clickable (touchable) parts are so tiny, it is virtually impossible to "click" them (they are only about 1mm across).

Essentially, the new nav is more or less nearly useless to me, and is certainly much less useful and much harder to use than the old version.

Question:

Can the nav bar be made to not widen as I zoom, so I can zoom and slide right to see the right hand edge? Or some other CSS kung fu applied that means I can usefully zoom into all parts of nav bar?

Or

Can there be an option at the bottom to use the old version of the nav (like the fullsite option)? I would change back in a second if I could.

Comment: To clarify:  you're using the full website on a mobile browser, right?  [I did pose a question about the mobile version of the site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343239/are-there-any-plans-for-the-mobile-version-of-the-website-to-incorporate-the-new) to see if they'd incorporate the new style, but I'm not sure if it's getting as much consideration - either good or bad.

Comment: @Makoto yes, fullsite on mobile browser - I'll make the clear in Q.

Comment: Do you have sticky nav enabled? Mine's disabled and I'm not experiencing any trouble with Edge on W10M.

Comment: @Stijn How do I do that on an iPhone/Chrome?

Comment: Not a browser feature, I mean the *Disable stickiness* option at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current; try choosing that option and see if it becomes usable on mobile.

Comment: Yep. That fixed it :) (except I visited www. not meta.)

Comment: FWIW, Chrome on Android appears to automatically "unsticky" the top-bar when you zoom in; guessing this is a feature they couldn't fake on iOS.

Comment: @Shog9 it's not so much that it isn't sticky, it's just stuck to a portion of the web page that is outside of the viewable area.

Comment: Bit of a pointless distinction there, eh @Tiny? It *behaves* as though it isn't sticky, allowing you to zoom and pan without difficulty (contrast with, for example, the full-site chat theme).

Comment: @Shog9 Sure, just as pointless as the distinction between Stack Overflow and Quora.

Comment: I see your problem and I'm looking into this. Not sure if we will be able to fix it but in the meantime you can disable stickiness (as mentioned above). There's actually [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344062/1147887) saying exactly the same thing but for some reason it's downvoted..

Comment: @pawel the disable sticky is a good enough work around, but it is useless if you don't enable that, and practically no one knows about it, so virtually all mobile users will be annoyed. Can't you just remove the "cool" stickiness which is actually crap for mobile users, maybe make it default enabled for mobile, disabled for desktop? Ie have 2 settings? Note too the reverse logic; you *enable* the option to *disable* the setting. The option should be reversed in name, ie "enable sticky", so the presence of a check mark agrees with enabling the option.

Comment: we're trying to not add too many options - it's really hard to maintain things that are customizable. and still - we have preference for stickiness and it might be weird for users if we ignore that preference on mobile only because it's mobile. also most of mobile users actually use mobile theme, so this is not a problem for them (re: "_all mobile users will be annoyed_").

Comment: @Paweł: Can the settings option be reversed? I mean rather than keeping the sticky on by default and then disabling it in settings, can it be like unsticky by default and then enabling it in settings? That way most people would be happy (*IMO guessing the sentiment from many meta posts on the same topic*).

Comment: @Abhitalks that would beat the whole point of the new top bar.

Comment: @paw quite so; mobile users *who select fullsite mode* will be annoyed. Abhitalks has a point: Why not opt out of sticky by default? And that leads to a bigger  question... who exactly says that the sticky option is a good idea? If it's such a great idea, why not put it to a community vote and let the debate/trial begin? If you want to reduce maintenance/options, one good way would be to eliminate sticky nav altogether. Sticky has few benefits IMHO; on iPhone you can one-tap (top edge) to instantly scroll to the top of a web page anyway. What does that leave as stick's value proposition?

Comment: @shadow and what exactly *is* the point of the new nav bar's sticky mode (over the new nav bar's non-sticky mode)? Are the benefits more pronounced in sticky mode? Would it work (as well) if there was no sticky option? Have there been A/B tests?  Is there any doc?

Comment: @Bohemian SE decided that majority of the people prefer the navigation part of a site to be sticky. Personally I disagree.

Comment: @shadow is there any supporting evidence for that decision? I'm with you; I'll refrain from using emotive terms... let's just say I would vote "no"

Comment: @Bohemian see [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5747692#5747692) for Shog response in chat, you can also read above and below for some more details.

Comment: you can find more details on reasoning [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/)

Comment: @Pawe: There's an easy solution. In the CSS, put a media query for a screen size smaller than _x_ that disables the sticky header automatically.

Answer (score 14):

To turn off stickiness, visit:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

and check the `Disable stickiness` option.